# How can I add the sku code in [commerce-order:commerce-email-order-items]

Tags: commerce

While the shortcode [commerce-order:commerce-email-order-items] is used to send several commerce emails, it does not includes SKU code. How can I add sku code or edit the output of [commerce-order:commerce-email-order-items]

Answer (score 0):

Some tokens are generated by code others by views. This token is generated by code

So edit commerce_email.module and around line 420 you will see commerce_email_order_items function here you can add the sku.

**Take in mind that this is not an ideal solution** See [hook_tokens_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/7)

Comment: This is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes it is, but i could not find another way of doing this. there is some kind of hook to alter tokens?

Comment: `hook_tokens_alter()` is indeed the way to alter tokens implemented by other modules. I would be surprised if there isn't a token for the SKU code; if there isn't, a module could be created to implement it with `hook_tokens()` e `hook_tokens_info()`.

Comment: There should be a sku token, thats for sure. But as commerce_email does not let you change/add tokens/fields or whatever to its order-summary-table function because it is hardcoded i think the propper way is with hook_tokens_alter

Answer (score 0):

The best way:

- Go to: `admin/structure/views/view/commerce_cart_summary/edit/`
- Under `Fields` you should change:
  Commerce Belegzeile: Product
  Erscheint in: commerce_line_item:product,     commerce_line_item:product_discount.
- Set the same settings from: `admin/structure/views/view/commerce_cart_form/edit/`
- Delete the line for the `Title`.

Now you can change the output over the product-variation-types-sites under Basket:
admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types/

Now you have a very good looking and adjustable order confirmation email.